# HTTP Request Include Equals checkbox can't be unchecked

Tags: jmeter, http-request-parameters, jmeter-5.0

When defining HTTP Request, there's a checkbox for each parameter: `Include Equals`

This checkbox can't be unchecked even when choosing different method or parameter.

I don't see any reference in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) for using it.

Why is this checkbox shown? Is there any usage for it?

[image]

Also it seems that Content-Type value per parameter is ignored,in GET it isn't sent:

```
GET http://www.google.com/?token=0Bfdsa

GET data:
```

In POST it send the regular `www-form-urlencoded`:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: same issue for me

Comment: Is this issue solved?

Comment: @PrasadLele not that I know

Comment: Please check my answer

Comment: @PrasadLele what answer?

Comment: Please check my comment in the answer section. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've also stumbled upon what does it mean, and I think I've found it.  It gives you the option to include `=` (equals) sign or not for **parameters with no value**: `foo=` vs. `foo`.  If the parameter has a value you cannot uncheck *"Include Equals?"*:

```
| Name: | Value | Include Equals? |
|-------|-------|:---------------:|
| foo   |       |       [x]       |
| bar   |       |       [ ]       |
| baz   | qux   |       [x]       |
```

The above configuration generates the following url-encoded form:

```
foo=&bar&baz=qux
```

The *"Content-Type"* appears used with the *"Use multipart/form-data"* option checked – every parameter is sent as a separate part and its own `Content-Type`:

```
[x] Use multipart/form-data

| Name: | Value | Content-Type |
|-------|-------|--------------|
| foo   |       | text/x-foo   |
| bar   |       | text/x-bar   |
| baz   | qux   | text/x-baz   |
```

The generated request looks like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=zIVpNBG_m1irxcTtk7ByTwBgDHbsjB1UjTdRTS

--zIVpNBG_m1irxcTtk7ByTwBgDHbsjB1UjTdRTS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="foo"
Content-Type: text/x-foo; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


--zIVpNBG_m1irxcTtk7ByTwBgDHbsjB1UjTdRTS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="bar"
Content-Type: text/x-bar; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


--zIVpNBG_m1irxcTtk7ByTwBgDHbsjB1UjTdRTS
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="baz"
Content-Type: text/x-baz; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

qux
--zIVpNBG_m1irxcTtk7ByTwBgDHbsjB1UjTdRTS--
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it worked for me,

I unchecked 'use multipart/form-data' and from header pass 'Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wanted to send content type per parameter, not global content type